# CodeDeploy or CodeCommit in AWS is changing File Type in S3 Bucket during Push?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-code-deploy, aws-codecommit

I am trying to connect the content of a static Website in an S3 bucket to a CodeCommit repo via CodeDeploy.

However, when I set up a repo via CodeCommit and a CodeDeploy Pipeline and when I push changes to my S3 bucket of my HTML file, the [static HTML page doesn't load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICrHC.png)instead my browser screen either briefly flashes or it [instead downloads the HTML file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r3zD.png)

I know I have the [S3 bucket configured correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRrLW.png) because when I test my .html file via it's public URL, [it loads as expect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUhOP.png)

Addtionally, when I download my HTML file via my S3 bucket BEFORE I push commit changes, the same file downloads. However, when I download the newly committed HTML file from S3, it's corrupted. Which makes me think it's an issue in how I've configured CodeDeploy, but can't figure it out.

I believe I have the [header information configured correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGPXA.png)

The S3 Bucket policy [Bucket policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZpHh.png) allows for reading of objects. CodePipeline [successfully pushes my repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbLWl.png) changes to my S3 Bucket. But for some reason, even through S3 still sees the file type as HTML, it's not configuring as such after a push from CodeDeploy. Additionally, when I try to download the new pushed HTML file and open it, [the HTML code is all jumbled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a3CA.png)

Any help or insights is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the details or configuration you are using when you are uploading the file to s3 using code deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Eureka! I found the solution (by accident).

Just in case others run into this problem: When configuring a deployment pipeline in CodePipeline, if you don't select "Extract file before deploy" in your deployment configuration step, CodePipeline will instead deploy any code commit HTML files (and I assume other files types as well) as "octet-streams". Enabling "Extract file before deploy" fixed this problem.

Now I will be able to finally sleep tonight!